# Teradata 15: Failure 5616 The user is not authorized to grant or revoke role

Tags: teradata, database-administration

I am using a second most powerful DBA account SYSDBA to assign a user to a role.  Simple task, right, but i got this error.

```
   grant "$ROLE" to "$user_name";
```

*** Failure 5616 The user is not authorized to grant or revoke role 'ROLE'

Then i search the web, Teradata has a nice document:

Only the user DBC, or a user granted a role WITH ADMIN OPTION, or a user with an applicable role (current role or a role nested within it) that is granted a role WITH ADMIN OPTION has the right to GRANT/REVOKE the role to/from another user or role.

What is the SQL syntax that I can fix this issue?

I tried the following according to some research.  But did not work

```
 grant "role_dba" to sysdba with admin option;
 grant "role_dba" to sysdba;
```

Comment: Did SYSDBA create the role? What does `SELECT RoleName, Grantee, Grantor, WithAdmin FROM DBC.RoleMembers WHERE Grantee='SYSDBA' AND RoleName='{role name}';` return?

Comment: I believe that I accidentally created this role by DBC. SELECT RoleName, Grantee, Grantor, WithAdmin 
FROM DBC.RoleMembersV
WHERE 
--Grantee='SYSDBA' AND 
RoleName='role_1';



role_1,   DBC,    SYSDBA,Y 
role_1,   user_1, DBC,N 
role_1,   user_2, DBC,N

Comment: `SYSDBA` should be able to grant the role `role_1` to another user, say `user_3`, because it is a member of the role with admin based on your results. The other users are members of the role `role_1` but do not have "with admin". Am I missing something?

Comment: sysdba is missing the admin right option and i do not know the syntax and how to add that right from DBC.

Comment: What does `SELECT RoleName, CreatorName FROM DBC.RoleInfoV WHERE RoleName = 'role_1';` return?

Comment: You are right, the role was created by sysdba:           role_1,SYSDBA.  So why sysdba can not assign this role to other users?

Comment: `RoleMembers` should have a row showing that SYSDBA is a `Grantee` of the role `Role_1`. If it doesn't, it suggests that maybe the role was revoked from SYSDBA. As the creator, you should be able to grant it back, perhaps as DBC if you have the password. Or you could drop the role and start over.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95759/discussion-between-dave-and-rob-paller).